# Javascript: How to store a variable in a null variable in a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

In the `startGame()`method, I am trying to store the selected phrase from the `getRandomPhrase()` method to the null property. It keeps throwing me an error saying

> Game.activePhrase is null

What am I doing wrong?

Game.js:

```
class Game {

  constructor() {
    this.missed = 0;
    //directly put the phrases in the constructor
    this.phrases = [new Phrase("hello world"),
      new Phrase("Wolf on wall street"),
      new Phrase("Despite making"),
      new Phrase("Karen took the kids"),
      new Phrase("alright about to head out")
    ];
    this.activePhrase = null;
  }

  getRandomPhrase() {
    //returns 5 of the random phrases
    return this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)];
  }

  startGame() {
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    phrs.addPhraseToDisplay();
    return this.activePhrase(phrs); //trying to store it by doing this
  }
}
```

App.js

```
const game = new Game();
game.startGame();
console.log(`Active Phrase - phrase: ${game.activePhrase.phrase}`);
```

Comment: `this.activePhrase = phrs;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign value to activePhase **variable** before returning it from startGame method

```
this.activePhrase = phrs;
```

Like

```
  startGame() {
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    phrs.addPhraseToDisplay();
    this.activePhrase = phrs; //Key to fix your issue
    return this.activePhrase;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned to `.activePhrase` (you tried to call `.activePhrase` as if it was a function, but it's not). Try assigning `phrs` to `this.activePhrase` instead:

```
this.activePhrase = phrs;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.activePhrase` is not a functoin - therefore `this.activePhrase(phrs)` will not do anything. Simply assign the value:

```
this.activePhrase = phrs;
```